# Lucene.net 4.8 - IDE doesn't recognize Lucene.Net.Standard as well as the StandardAnalyzer's

Tags: c#, lucene.net, analyzer

Im using Lucene.net version 4.8beta, and when trying to use an Analyzer it doesnt recognize StandardTokenizer. I am already using Lucene.Net.Analysis. I am using Visual Studio

I have already tried using NuGet package manager to uninstall, and then reinstall the beta. I have an old project that uses Lucene.net 3.03 that uses some of the standard Tokenizers such as WhitespaceTokenizer and LowerCaseFilter. All the guides in the 4.8 Documentation mention using StandardTokenizer as well.

```
TokeStream result = new WhiteSpaceTokenizer(reader);
result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
```

I expect the function to be useable, but this just tells me that it doesnt recognize it.

Comment: What exactly is not recognized? Could you add full example of how you are using those classes, and what error you are getting?

Comment: Did you figure out what your problem was?

Answer (score 25):

Guess I just figured out why.

Bumped into the same situation. NuGet Manager will only offer v3.03 as the "latest stable version" so I had to install versino 4.8.0-beta00006 via command line

```
Install-Package Lucene.Net -Pre
```

As Lucene.Net Quick Start Guide advised.

However, what they "forget" to tell you is that, you will need to install another separate one:

```
Install-Package Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common -Version 4.8.0-beta00006
```

This one will bring closure to all the gaps.

Man why don't they package everything all together... when I'm buying a car I'm expecting a car. Have to buy steering wheel separately? That's awkward...

Comment: I upvoted because this helped me find the solution. While agree this is awkward, it is generally best to keep answers constructively focused. Thanks for sharing your knowledge here